# JSon Stringify and Parse implementation

Tags: json, parsing, stringify

JSON Parse and stringify are the two function to convert a string into object (by deserialization) and an object into string (by serialization of the object).

Can anyone explain me the exact methodology for the both function? I expect an answer describing the steps in detail.

Note: I am not looking for a difference but the methodology for implementation.
Just the steps in simple English words.

Comment: There is a detailed description of `JSON.stringify` in the [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json.stringify). The JSON format is described in [ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-404.htm), and the rest of the behaviour of `JSON.parse` is described in the ECMAScript standard, in the chapter before the one which describes `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Explaination in simple terms much have been much better, yet the link helped me a lot in my research. Thanks once again.

Comment: I am not looking for the difference, but the implementation.